# How do you add labels to the result formed by Java 8 groupingby function?

Tags: java, java-8, nested

I currently have a class,

```
public class Person {
    private String country;
    private String age;
    private String name;
}
```

Taking a List of this Person class  as a argument,

```
List<Person>
```

I managed to group them in the following data structure using **Java 8 group by (collection)** function :

```
Map<String, Map<String, Set<String>>>
```

Example:

```
 USA={
     21=
       [
         John,
         Peter.
         Andrew
       ],
      22=
       [
         Eric,
         Mark
       ]

     ]
  },
 France = {
      etc....
```

Below is my function :

```
  public static Map<String, Map<String, Set<String>>> getNestedMap(List<Person> persons) {
    return persons.stream().collect(
    groupingBy(Person::getCountry,
      groupingBy(Person::getAge,
          mapping(Person::getName, toSet())

      )));
  }
```

However, I wanted my data structure to look like this, with labels for each level. Is there a way **Java 8 group by (collection)** can help achieve this? or is there better way?

```
 Country = USA,
 AgeList = {
     Age = 21,
     People =
       [
         [Name = John],
         [Name = Peter],
         [Name = Andrew]
       ],
      Age = 22,
      People =
       [
         [Name = Eric],
         [Name = Mark]
       ]

     ]
  },
 Country = France, 
 AgeList = {
       etc....
```

Comment: I would probably not (just) use streams for this. Streams are a tool, and if you're finding yourself jumping through hoops to use them it's worth asking if they're really the right tool for the job. Even if you *could* get the structure you're looking for in a single stream expression, the resulting code would be difficult for future readers (including yourself) to understand.

Comment: That “data structure” you have shown in your question is not a data structure, but a textual representation, apparently JSON syntax, which is JavaScript syntax, but not Java. When you want a certain *data structure*, you should specify a data structure.

Answer (score 3):

You've started with an input (a series of `Person` instances) and a tool (`.groupingBy()`), rather than an input and a *desired output*. Identify that first, *then* determine which tool(s) are the most appropriate way to transform the input into the desired output.

For example, you might want to end up with a `Country` object, that contains a name and a list of `Age` objects, each of which contains an age and a set of `People` objects. With that resulting structure in mind you could you could do a single `.groupingBy()` pass to group by country, and pass the resulting lists into a `Country(String name, List<Person> people)` constructor, which then in turn does another `.groupingBy()` pass to group by age, and invokes an `Age(int age, List<Person>)` constructor.

If your goal is to then serialize this structure into a JSON-ish string, you can easily do so in `Country.toString()`, now that you have the data in the structure you need.

It's always a good idea to separate structural concerns (like transforming from a `List<Foo>` to something complex like a `Map<Bar, Map<Baz, Set<Foo>>>`) from representational concerns (like then rendering a string representation of that complex structure). You'll find solving the two steps separately is often significantly easier - and easier to maintain - than doing it all in one fell swoop.