# Can you always nest a JSON object in a JSON array?

Tags: python, arrays, json

When sending JSON data via a POST, PUT or similar does it matter if you send all objects nested in a Array?

Eg. Is **THIS**

```
"""
{ 
  "candle" : {"ask": null,
  "bid": null,
  "complete": "True",
  "mid": {"c": "0.80628", "h": "0.80628", "l": "0.80628", "o": "0.80628"},
  "time": "2017-09-08T17:27:15.000000000Z",
  "volume": "6"}
}
 """
```

**AND**

```
 """
{ 
  "candle" : [{"ask": null,
  "bid": null,
  "complete": "True",
  "mid": {"c": "0.80628", "h": "0.80628", "l": "0.80628", "o": "0.80628"},
  "time": "2017-09-08T17:27:15.000000000Z",
  "volume": "6"}]
}
 """
```

**Equivalent?**

I would imagine it depended on the server. But is it best practice to only send the object if there is only one?

Or is it common to just send everything as an Array?

It would reduce complexity if I could just send everything in an Array

Comment: That's not JSON. JSON only uses double quotes around strinhgs, not single quotes.

Comment: You should never try to construct JSON yourself, use the `json.dump` function. It knows the correct syntax.

Comment: ipython just formats a dict representation of JSON much better than a string... I fixed it

Comment: It's not formatting it as JSON, it's formatting it using Python syntax.

Comment: I think this is irrelevant to the question. It should be correct now if anyone actually wanted to use it

Comment: It's not relevant to the question, I was just trying to educate you on the difference between JSON and Python representations.

Comment: yes that's appreciated. I took a short cut by not using `dumps` because ipython puts nice returns in. `dumps` just gives a big long string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would imagine it depended on the server.

Yes, a server will generally expect data in a particular format. If you send data in some other format the server will likely not know what you're saying.

> But is it best practice to only send the object if there is only one?

There's no particular best practice, it depends on the data in question. Using arrays can allow for more flexibility (e.g. maybe in the future you'll want to accept multiple objects) but flexibility can be confusing, or add unnecessary complexity. It depends.

> Or is it common to just send everything as an Array?

No, data should be structured in a meaningful way.

> It would reduce complexity if I could just send everything in an Array

I don't see how that's true in the general case (the opposite is probably more often true), but if it's a specific issue with the service you're working with maybe you can submit that feedback to the service owners and they can explore changing the API. If it's your service then go for it - use whatever data format makes sense to you.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks. Well I like using lit comp in python. So if I always used a list comp and `json.dumps` it. It would always be in a `Array` - That's what I was thinking

Comment: Use the right tool for the job - list comprehensions *are* really nice, but focus on the problem and the goal, rather than trying to massage the goal into something that uses the tools you like. I posted [some similar advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45557760/113632) in another question (about Java) recently.

Comment: @JamesSchinner Something that doesn't seem to have been mentioned in any answer. You could, in theory, just structure your data as nested dictionaries to an arbitrary level and never touch an array (provided that you always had meaningful keys to make sub-dictionaries). However, dictionaries do not maintain order. If you need to supply objects in a particular order, then you can supply an array, which will maintain order, and configure the server to parse them in the order they were intended to be parsed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to follow an existing protocol you have no choice.

If you design the protocol by yourself then you have to choose. For a (forever) single object the array-approach has no advantage. However, if more objects can occur in the future the array-approach is more flexible and future-proof.

Comment: thanks, so there is no industry consensus on what is acceptable? In my case I will need to find out exactly how the sent data needs to be arranged.

Comment: It is not about consensus, it's about purpose. It's reasonable to use an array where a container for *repeated things* is needed. The array is not justified in situations where a *single thing* is used.

Answer (score 1):

They aren't equivalent, array and objects are different.

But it hardly matters,
In example 1 you can have only one candle.
In example 2 you can have multiple candles.
I don't see any reason to use array if you want to represent only one candle. And complexity (computational at least)  will be less if you use object instead of array.

Answer (score 0):

It is not equivalent: a list of items is not equivalent to a single item.

Comment: I think there is a subtle difference between Equality and equivalent in this case. The question is more nuanced

Comment: They're not equivalent or equal in any sense, unless the server is prepared to receive singletons instead of one-element lists.

Comment: To be clear there is no such notion of equivalence in JSON; `{ "foo": { "bar": "baz" } }` is a wholly different structure than `{ "foo": [ { "bar": "baz" } ] }`.